# while reloading angular page getting error as cannot GET/page.html

Tags: angularjs

There is no a clear solution for my below question in stackoverflow, i have searched for many but its not suitable

**note**: am not using **GRUNT**

Actually am developing a application using Node and Angular,

while using angular-route to route a page from application its working fine, but reloading browser shows me **Cannot GET /secure/home**

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('Whizzrd', ['ngRoute']).
            config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

                $routeProvider.
                    when('/secure/home', {
                        templateUrl: '/pages/static/home.html', 
                        controller: 'homeController'
                    });

                $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false});
            }]);
```

moving through home.html through application is working fine, but while reloading the page using browser am getting error as

```
Cannot GET /secure/home
```

Am stuck with this for more than 2 days, Help will be appreciated really